# How do I export the result of a promise chain to a separate module?

Tags: node.js, google-api, async-await, es6-promise

I would like to use the result of googleApi.js inside index.js but am having trouble accessing the data from index.js. The result is either undefined or a promise object depending on the solutions I have tried. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

index.js:

```
const googleClient = require('./googleApi.js')

let one = '52.4362,4.7291'
let two = '52.2672,5.0813'

const test = async() => {
    const result = await googleClient.getTimeAndDistance(one,two)
    console.log(result)
}

test()
```

googleApi.js

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'MY_API_KEY',
    Promise: Promise
})

getTimeAndDistance = (origin, destination) => {
    googleMapsClient.directions({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        language: 'en',
        units: 'metric',
    })
        .asPromise()
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json.routes[0].legs[0]
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

module.exports.getTimeAndDistance = getTimeAndDistance
```

The code in googleApi.js works and I am able to log the result to the console, but I am unable to access that data outside of the module even when I export the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **`index.js`** **return** `googleMapsClient` from inside `getTimeAndDistance` to make available the `res.json.routes[0].legs[0]` outside the `getTimeAndDistance`.

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'MY_API_KEY',
    Promise: Promise
})

getTimeAndDistance = (origin, destination) => {
 return googleMapsClient.directions({
//^^^^^ 
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        language: 'en',
        units: 'metric',
        })
        .asPromise()
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json.routes[0].legs[0]
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

module.exports.getTimeAndDistance = getTimeAndDistance
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing things a bit differently but ultimately it is the same as your solution to export the promise.